# TCL - searching for ip addresses in a file

Tags: tcl

i have a file that contains lots of different ip addresses. 
what i need to do is, to find these ip addresses and put them in a variable or list or a file so later i can do more action to them.

i have this regexp to find the ip address:

```
% set ip [open subnets.txt r]
% set sub [read $ip]
% regexp {(?:\d+\.){3}\d+(\/)([0-9]+)} $sub a
```

but it only gives me the 1st ip address of the file.

can anyone give me a better solution to this?

Thanks so much

Comment: You're probably better with `(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\/)([0-9]+)` as the RE. (It doesn't handle all ways of writing an IP address, nor even all ways of writing an IPv4 address, but won't overread so much.)

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing the a couple of [options](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regexp.htm)

```
set addresses [regexp -all -inline {(?:\d+\.){3}\d+/[0-9]+} $sub]
```